# How to break down a string and exclude some words?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have extended the blacklisted words set with `It` just to discover that some unit tests are now failing.

I didn't notice that `I` in notes is now excluded as well, since it matches `It`, which isn't what I intended.

```
notes = @"I was out with Jenny for dinner. It was raining all night.";

NSString * const BLACKLISTEDWORDS = @"in,it,It";

NSArray *words = [notes componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
for (NSString *word in words) {
    if([BLACKLISTEDWORDS rangeOfString:word].location == NSNotFound]) {

    }
}
```

Is there any better way to create a blacklist approach?

**Solution**:
Matt solution works fine. To capture it as code for this solution:

```
NSSet *blackList = [NSSet setWithArray:[BLACKLISTEDWORDS componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
for (NSString *word in words) {
    if (![blackList containsObject:word]) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are merely comparing the words of `notes` against *a single string*, namely `@"in,it,It"`. So "i" will succeed, "n" will succeed, "n,i" will succeed, and so on. That isn't at all what you want.

Instead, break the blacklisted words *into individual words*. Separate them into a set (NSSet), and look to see if each word of `notes` is a member of that set.